# How to access jEditable DatePicker options (onSelect, minDate, maxDate)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jeditable, mindate

I am using jEditable together with jQuery DatePicker. I am trying to do validation for a date range. For example, if 1st June 2010 is selected in the `startDate` field, the user cannot select dates before 1st June 2010 in the `endDate` field and vice versa.

All of the other codes are working except the validation part. What I understand is that the full version of jQuery-ui DatePicker is included in the jEditable version but I do not know how to use it.

This is the DatePicker I am using: https://github.com/qertoip/jeditable-datepicker/tree/master/src

Sample Demo of DatePicker plugin: http://thesingularity.pl/jeditable-datepicker-demo/

My script

```
  $( '#startDate' ).editable('AppUpdateServlet',{
  indicator : '<img src="images/indicator.gif">',
  type: 'datepicker',
  datepicker: {
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    //minDate: '+1w'            (this is working)
    onSelect: function() {
       //the alert is working
       //alert("working");

       //not working
       $('#endDate').datepicker('option', {minDate: $(this).datepicker('getDate')});

     }
  }
});


$( '#endDate' ).editable('AppUpdateServlet',{
  indicator : '<img src="images/indicator.gif">',
  type: 'datepicker',
  datepicker: {
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function() {
    //not working
    $('#startDate').datepicker('option', {minDate: $(this).datepicker('getDate')});
    }
  }
});
```

HTML snippet

```
<span  id="startDate">
    <%=test.getStartDate()%>
</span>
<span  id="endDate">
    <%=test.getEndDate()%>
</span>
```

Comment: Have you checked that your `#startDate` and `#endDate` selectors match up with what ends up in the DOM?

Comment: How do I check that? I think the problem lies in the addition of the jEditable. With that, there may be extra parameters to input so  $('#startDate').datepicker('option', {minDate: $(this).datepicker('getDate')}); does not work

Comment: Use a DOM inspector such as the one in Chrome ("inspect element") or Firebug for Firefox, that should tell you how to identify the text inputs, I don't think the datapicker is actually attached to the `#startDate` and `#endDate` spans.

Comment: I see a whole chunk of text, not sure to to start debugging. My selectors for the editable is correct. The problem I have is I dont know how to modify the datapicker inside the editable function. Problem is in this line:

$('#startDate').datepicker('option', {minDate:$(this).datepicker('getDate')});

Does $('#startDate').datepicker refers to the datapicker inside the editable or are there are parameters needed.

Comment: If the text input really is `#startDate`, then `$('#startDate').datepicker('option', ...` should work; but `#startDate` is a `<span>` in your HTML, not a text input.

Comment: I am quite sure using `<span>` is alright as it works well without the 'onSelect' funtion.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the problem by removing jEditable and using pure jQuery Datepicker. Thanks for your help. Admin / Mods plz close this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not possible to reference to datepicker in jEditable. I have switched to using pure jQuery Datepicker to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
('.editDate').editable('myUrl', {
        type: 'datepicker',
        datepicker: {minDate: 0}
    });
```